# What causes Hazelcast to throw an InterruptedException during map.lock()

Tags: hazelcast

I'm using IMap to do locking, following how it's explained here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hazelcast/9YFGh3xwe8I

```
IMap<Object, Object> locks = hazelcastInstance.getMap("locks");
locks.lock(someStr);
try {
    //do stuff
} finally {
    locks.unlock(someStr);
}
```

Occasionally, the line

```
locks.locks(someStr)
```

Is causing the error

```
com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.lang.InterruptedException:
Call BasicInvocation{ serviceName='hz:impl:lockService',op=com.hazelcast.concurrent.lock.operations.LockOperation{
serviceName='hz:impl:lockService', callId=2854669, invocationTime=1441146297670, waitTimeout=-900001, callTimeout=60000}, 
partitionId=215, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=0, callTimeout=60000, 
target=Address[*.*.*.*]:****, backupsExpected=0, backupsCompleted=0} was interrupted
at com.hazelcast.util.ExceptionUtil.rethrow(ExceptionUtil.java:52)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.getSafely(BasicInvocationFuture.java:200)
at com.hazelcast.concurrent.lock.LockProxySupport.lock(LockProxySupport.java:79)
at com.hazelcast.concurrent.lock.LockProxySupport.lock(LockProxySupport.java:73)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.lock(MapProxyImpl.java:256)
```

The cluster in Production consists of two nodes.

I am unable to reproduce the issue locally.
I've read for a similar exception, it had to do with the app server clock times getting two far out of sync, but that is not the case for me.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?
It seems like my usage of IMap is very straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Usually [InterruptedException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) means that a thread that is executing `locks.lock(someStr);` was interrupted from some other thread of your program.

For example you can interrupt another thread with Thread.interrupt(), Future.cancel(true) or ExecutorService.shutdownNow().

Comment: this solved my problem. You can put a break point wherever the used Threah.interrupt() and debug where the error started.